# Symfony: update database schema to reflect deleted table

Tags: database, symfony, schema

Using Symfony 5 I had some problems with an entity so deleted it with a view to rebuilding it. I also manually deleted the database table. When I now try to remake the entity using php bin/console make:entity and then php bin/console make:migration it is trying to perform and alter to the table, implying that it is expecting the table to still exist.

When I run php bin/console doctrine:schema:validate it gives:

### Mapping

[OK] The mapping files are correct.

### Database

[ERROR] The database schema is not in sync with the current mapping file.

How can I update the schema to reflect the fact that the table has been manually deleted?

Many thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: BTW: if you had problems with 1 entity you should have removed one ROW and not a TABLE - AFAIK `bin/console make:migration` should generate a file that should contain the add code for the missing table, you can then use `bin/console make:migrate` to execute (dont forget to make backups ;) )

Comment: Yes, I was making a lot of changes, including to primary and foreign keys and thought it would be easier just to start again. From the point of view of creating the new entity it was easier to do it this way, it's just I now have the above problem.

php bin/console make:migration it is trying to perform and alter to the table, implying that it is expecting the table to still exist.

Comment: Make sure you clear the Symfony cache.  Might want to just remove the entire var/cache directory.  And empty out the migrations table.  I personally avoid using migrations while developing.  The doctrine:schema commands work just fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you want to do this the hard way, just try

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --complete
```

--complete will sync the db with the current schema

Comment: This didn't initially work so I did what Cerad suggested, then did this, and kerpow! Thanks for the help.